# How do I resolve React JSX's adjacent component wrapper error when I need to dynamically add markup in between elements?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, markup

I have a `TypeList` component that will show `Type` components in a table view like so:

[image]

I need to give the `TypeList` CSS with `display: table` and then add rows for every three types that are listed, so every three types need to be nested inside a `<div class="table-row"></div>`. I tried to do this with the logic below but get the adjacent JSX error. Is there something I can change to solve this?

**TypeList.js**

```
import Type from './Type'

const TypeList = ({info}) => (
  <ul className="table">
    <div class="table-row">
    {
      info.map(function (type, idx) {
        // onclick details taken care of here
        if (idx === map.length - 1){
          return (
            <Type key={idx} name={type.name} />
            </div>
          )
        } else if (idx === 2) {
          return (
            <Type key={idx} name={type.name} />
            </div>
            <div class="table-row">
          )
        } else {
          return (<Type key={idx} name={type.name} />)
        }
      })
    }
  </ul>
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit ugly but it's the only solution I've found for problems like this.

```
function renderstuff(...) {
    return (
        <div> 
            (...)
        </div>
    ).props.children;
}
```

This function renders your things in a `<div>` wrapper and then strips off the wrapper by returning `.props.children`.

It might work in your case, just extract the contents of your `.map` callback into a function, wrap your markup and return `props.children` of the wrapper.

Comment: You might want to look into solving this with CSS rather than markup by using flexbox and setting `flex-basis` to 30% on the children. It would probably be a better solution.

Comment: what do you mean by extract contents into a function? do you mean extract it to a variable?

Answer (score 0):

I have rewritten the map function so that you don't have this error:

```
const TypeList = ({info}) => (
  <ul className="table">
    <div class="table-row">
    {
      info.splice(0, 2).map(function (type, idx) {
        return <Type key={idx} name={type.name} />;
      })
    }
    </div>
    <div class="table-row">
    {
      info.map(function (type, idx) {
        return (
          <Type key={idx} name={type.name} />
        );
      })
    }
    </div>
  </ul>
)
```